# EclipseLink in Play 2.1.0

Tags: playframework-2.0, eclipselink

Can i use eclipselink with play framework 2.1.0. last one use ebean as default orm engine, what is pros and cons of ebean and is it better than the eclipselink?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that it should be possible to use eclipselink and play 2.1.0. together. I am currently trying to make it work.

I'll let you know if I'll be successful. Currently it seems that all you need to configure is add following dependency to Build.Scala

```
 "org.eclipse.persistence" % "javax.persistence" % "2.0.0"
```

Then you need to continue as it is described here on http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaJPA

On the other hand I don't have any experience with ebean so I can't tell you how it is from the performance point of view. From what I've read I thing that setting up ebean with play will be much easier, but afterwards there will better documentation for classical JPA with eclipselink which might be useful for the development.